# Changing font colors after certain time duration

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put some text on a website, such that it changes color onmouseover and returns to the original color onmouseout after some (say 2 seconds) time delay.

Is it possible to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: a pure CSS3 solution is acceptable for you?

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not a place for "gimme the codez" or "can I do this?". SO is not google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can do something like this (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QdBdd/))

HTML:

```
<a id='v1'>Hello</a>​
```

JS:

```
​setTimeout(function() {
    $('#v1').css('color','#777');
}​,2000);​
```

**Edit**: Full JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QdBdd/1/)

JS:

```
$('#v1').hover(function() {
     $(this).css('color','#777');   
}, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#v1').css('color','#000');
     },2000);
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

this kind of features should be provided by CSS3 where available, without involving setTimeout's or other kind of javascript. So, assuming you will choose one of previous proposed Javascript solution for IE, simply use this CSS for every other modern browser

html/css

```
<span>hover me</span>

span {
    color : green;
    -webkit-transition : color 2s linear;
    -msie-transition : color 2s linear;
    -moz-transition : color 2s linear;
    -o-transition : color 2s linear;
    transition : color 2s linear;
}

span:hover {
    color : red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onmouseout="timedFunction()"` to your text, using this function:

```
function timedFunction{    
    var timeout = setTimeout("changeColor()",timeInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`

Comment: Because they get `eval`ed, which is slow, hard to debug and has scope issues.

Comment: @Quentin what's the better way then?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working example using setTimeout;

css:
    .text {
      color: red;
    }
    .text.hover {
      color: yellow;
    }

javascript:

```
var timeoutId = null;
$(".text").hover(function() {
    if (timeoutId != null) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = null;
    }
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function () {
    var $element = $(this);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        $element.removeClass("hover");
    }, 500);
});​
```

And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9TJfD/8/

Comment: Why remove the class every half second? Once it is gone, it is gone and it won't come back unless you add it explicitly … and then you have to clear the interval to do so. This approach is inefficient and harder to debug.

Comment: Yeah, that was a big mistake, I changed it.